# If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $m^\ast(A) = 0$, then there exist $B, C ∈ \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A = B \setminus C$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, outer-measure

Is this a true claim or false? Recall that $m$ is Lebesgue measure and $m^\ast$ is Lebesgue outer measure. Also, $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ in this case represents the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.

I know that since $m^\ast(A) = 0$, then it can be shown that $A$ is Lebesgue measurable and hence $m(A) = 0$. I also know that since $B,C$ are Borel measurable, then they are Lebesgue measurable. My current strategy is to find a $B$ and $C$ that are Borel measurable and hence Lebesgue measurable such that $A = B \setminus C$ since $A$ is Lebesgue measurable. I'm not sure how to go about this.

Perhaps the claim isn't true?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If $B, C$ are in the Borel $\sigma-$algebra then so is $B \setminus C$. So it boils down to whether you think every measure zero set is Borel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment suggests, for all Borel sets $B,C$, $B \setminus C$ is a Borel set.

Since there exists a [non Borel Lebesgue measure zero set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1684143/290189) $A$, $A$ can't be a Borel set, so the claim is not true.

Comment: Perfect. Do we have a clear/simple example of a set $A$ with $m^\ast(A) = 0$ such that $A$ is Lebesgue measurable but not Borel measurable? Or only that we can guarantee the existence of one via the link you gave? Thanks.

Comment: @Darkdub, I can't think of any example simpler than the pre-image of a non-measurable subset of a Cantor set under $x \mapsto x + \phi(x)$, where $\phi$ is the Cantor Lebesgue function.  The simplicity of this example can be subjective.  When I first heard that in a tutorial, I was lost.  In fact, I've enhanced my memory of this through answering your question.